# Spring Boot Forms; hiding the path value and showing placeholder

Tags: java, forms, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I am having a small issue with Spring Boot forms displaying the information of the path value instead of the placeholder once you get to the editProfile.jsp. I want the input field to look like this;
[Edit Profile Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd0tI.png) instead of this [Wrong Edit Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OhkZ.png). I do not want my users to have to click, select and delete the auto completed value. I want it to show the placeholder only and allow them to overwrite what is shown with ease.

**This is the editProfile.jsp**

```
<%--@elvariable id="editProfile" type=""--%>
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="editProfile">
    <div class="MyForm form-group">
        <h1>Edit Profile</h1>
        <form:input type="email" class="MyInput" id="email" path="email" placeholder="${editProfile.email}" />

         <form:button type="submit" class="from-control">Submit</form:button>


    </div>

    <div>
        <img src="images/reg1.png" alt="picture">
    </div>



</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is the code specified in the Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "edit/{email}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getEditUserData(@PathVariable("email") String email, Model model) {

        AccountEntity accountInstance = accountRepo.findByEmail(email);
        model.addAttribute("editProfile", accountInstance);

        return "editProfile";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "edit/{email}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String enterEditUserData(@ModelAttribute("login") AccountEntity accountForm, @PathVariable("email") String email, Model model ) {
        AccountEntity accountInstance = accountRepo.findByEmail(email);
        accountInstance.setEmail(accountForm.getEmail());
        accountRepo.save(accountInstance);

        return "redirect:/login";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out; You have to add a model of a new Entity, so the path variable does not fill in with the instance of the specific path value. Here is the new code, and compare it to the one I sent above.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "edit/{email}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getEditUserData(@PathVariable("email") String email, Model model) {

        AccountEntity accountInstance = accountRepo.findByEmail(email);
        model.addAttribute("editProfile2", new AccountEntity());
        model.addAttribute("editProfile1", accountInstance);

        return "editProfile";
    }
```

```
<%--@elvariable id="editProfile" type=""--%>

<%--@elvariable id="editProfile2" type=""--%>
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="editProfile2">
    <div class="grid form-group">
        <h1>Edit Profile</h1>

        <form:input type="email" class="MyInput" id="email" path="email" placeholder='${editProfile1.email}' />


         <form:button type="submit" class="from-control">Submit</form:button>


    </div>
```